# Python executes mysteriously other phantom script

Tags: python, python-2.7, command-line

I had a strange situation:

In my folder /home/Komponenten/ were a lot of python scripts

When I started

> cd /home/Kompontenen
>
> /home/Kompontenen>python urlfilter.py

resulted in the execution of another script, i found out that it was in my case it was queue.py from the same folder

I though ok, there might be some code in urlfilter were I used the queue.py. Queue.py contained a little test with multithreading but nothing special

So I simply tried to move the queue.py file

After that urlfilter.py was executed normally and no error

So I still have no clue why the python interpreter executed queue.py instead of urlfilter.py

Answer (score 2):

In Python the import path contains `.` (working directory). Importing a module basically means executing it. That is why your importing of `queue` from `urlfilter.py` resulted in `queue` being executed. To avoid accidental execution of scripts by importing, you can check the `__name__` variable for the value `'__main__'`.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    do_not_execute_this_during_import()
```